# How do I get the template editor for Eclipse scala SKD?

Tags: html, eclipse, scala, playframework

I am trying to get started developing with the Eclipse Scala SDK with the Play Framework. But when I try to select an editor with which to open my views (*.scala.html), there is no option that I can find that will (a) open the file correctly and (b) use syntax highlighting. Right now I am just using the text editor option. I read on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215382/scala-ide-play-2-eclipse-plug-in-not-highlighting-syntax-for-scala-html-templa) that the correct editor is the Template editor, but I cannot find that editor and I don't know how to get new editors. I have tried Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations, but the template editor is not an option.